# Set theory: $n$ is a set in the naturals, if $x$ is in $n$, is $x$ also a natural number?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, natural-numbers

Im having trouble with a homework question from my Set Theory class. The question is, Let $n$ be a set and an element of the natural numbers. If $x$ is an element of $n$, is $x$ also an element of the natural numbers? My intuition says yes, since we built up the natural numbers using only the empty set, I would guess that $x$ is just $n-1$, but I'm having trouble proving this.

My class is using the Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory axioms.

Comment: What do you mean by **Let n be a set and an element of the natural numbers.** -- elements of the natural numbers are *numbers* not *sets*, so either $n$ is a set, or it is an element of natural numbers, but not both?

Comment: @gt6989b Yes, they are both elements of natural numbers and sets. See the [set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the [von Neumann construction of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers), the answer is yes.

Since $n=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, an element of $n$ is also an element of $\Bbb N$.

In the special case $n=0$ (that is, $n=\emptyset$) it is vacuously true as no set is an element of $n$.

---

With [Zermelo's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Zermelo_ordinals), the answer is also yes.

Here, $n=\{\{\dots\}\}$, where there are $n+1$ nested brackets. So except for the case $n=0$ (which is still vacuously true), $n$ has only one element, which is $n-1$, so any element of $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: This depends on the construction of the [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Zermelo_ordinals) that is presented in the OP's course. If it is von Neumann's construction (which is the most common these days), then you are right, but not if it is Zermelo's construction - see the Wikipedia link for definitions   See also Benecerraf's [What Numbers Could Not Be](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2183530?seq=1) for an interesting discussion of this, pointing out that it is a shortcoming in our mathematical foundations if definitions include unnecessary "implementation detail".

Comment: @RobArthan Agreed. I added this assumption in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave my comment, since, hopefully, the links are of interest. And it is an open problem how to resolve the problems pointed out be Benecerraf.

Comment: I should have specified, it is actually Zermelo's. How would that change the answer?

Comment: @sallyheroes Actually it's also yes, I modified the answer accordingly. But note that using Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (which is the most common) does not mean that you are using the Zermelo construction of natural numbers. The von Neumann construction is also valid in ZF.